# Akka compose futures of different types

Tags: akka, future

I have 3 `scala.concurrent.Future` of different types and need to compose them inside a `akka.dispatch.Futures.sequence`to got notified when all futures complete, futures is declared as:

```
Future<List<Request>> f1
Future<List<Offer>> f2
Future<Event> f3
```

I tried to put them inside a `Iterable<Future<Object>>` which is declared as `Iterable<Future<Object>> futureIterable = new ArrayList<>();`

as follows:

```
    Iterable<Future<Object>> futureIterable = new ArrayList<>();
    Future<Iterable<Future<Object>>> futureListOfInts=sequence(futureIterable,getContext().dispatcher());
```

I got this compilation message:

```
Error:(139, 67) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
inferred: scala.concurrent.Future<java.lang.Object>
equality constraints(s): scala.concurrent.Future<java.lang.Object>,java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

`Futures.sequence` works well in transforming an `Iterable[Future[A]]` in a `Future[Iterable[A]]` with object of the same tipe `A`.

To "wait" for the completition of different `Future`s, the more generic and idiomatic way is to `flatMap` them, like in the following snippet:

```
final ExecutionContext ec = getContext().dispatcher();

public Future<Result> composeFutures(Future<List<Request>> f1, Future<List<Offer>> f2, Future<Event> f3) {

    return f1.flatMap(new Mapper<List<Request>, Future<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public Future<Result> apply(List<Request> requestList) {
            return f2.flatMap(new Mapper<List<Offer>, Future<Result>>() {
                @Override
                public Future<Result> apply(List<Offer> offers) {
                    return f3.map(new Mapper<Event, Result>() {
                        @Override
                        public Result apply(Event event) {

                            // use requestList, offers, event
                            // to have your result
                            // ...

                            return new Result();
                        }
                    }, ec);
                }
            }, ec);
        }
    }, ec);

}
```

As you can see the `composeFutures` method will return a single `Future`, that will be completed when `f1`, `f2` and `f3` will be completed successfully. If one of them would fail, the failed future will be returned.